# who eats more fruits?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

in a party 3 brothers discussing:

first brother says  " I ate more fruit than 2nd brother and 2nd brother  ate more fruit than 3rd brother"

2nd brother says  " 3nd brother ate more than me also 3rd brother ate more than 1st brother"

3rd brother says " 2nd brother ate more that me and 1st brother ate the same as me "

now between two brother the person who has eaten the less fruit is the most honest person. base on that fact which sentences is not wrong?

1. 3rd ate more than others.
2. 2nd ate more than others.
3. 1st ate more than 2nd.
4. 2nd ate more than 1st.
5. 2nd ate more than 3rd.
6. 3rd ate more than 2nd.
7. 3rd ate more than 1st.
8. 1st ate more than 3rd.
9. all the brothers ate same amount of fruits

Comment: isnt this duplicate of puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77706/banana-at-party ? I wonder its same person posting that, this, and also https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77738/the-riddles-about-three-children

Comment: The two previous ones seem to have been posted by different people. (Though of course appearances may deceive.) This one might or might not be the same as one of the earlier ones. From how insistently it's being posted here, my guess is that it's a question from some sort of contest, aptitude test, etc.

Comment: yes its from my child class, could any one help me with it

Answer (score 1):

> If the 2nd brother says he ate more than himself, he must be lying about the 3rd brother eating more than the first brother, so the one that is true is 8.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, for future reference you should add >! before you answer so you don’t spoil it for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second statement is wrong. If it is right then

> he is lying about the 3rd brother eating more than the first brother

so

> number 8 is right.

Comment: the second statement is about 3rd guy . bad writing !